# Difference between @DataProvider and @Parameters in TestNG

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

- What is the difference between @DataProvider and @Parameters ?
- When should we use @DataProvider and when @Parameters ?

Comment: Could not got why Parameters if have Dataprovider :)

Comment: The stated reason for closing does not apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [@Parameters](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-testng-xml), the parameter values you provide are hardcoded in the test configuration file, `testng.xml`. Also, as far as I can recall, there is no way to specify the execution of the same test with varying values for a parameter. You provide one value for each parameter and that's it.

With [@DataProvider](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders), you provide a method that will generate the parameter values. They do not need to be hardcoded anywhere: you can compute them on the fly. For instance, you could fetch the current temperature from a website and use the resulting value as a parameter value. Or your could read them from a CSV file.

Also, you can provide multiple sets of values for the parameters. That way, you can run the same test multiple times with each desired combination of parameter values.